# My wordpress rest api json respond is prepended with a chevron charcter "<"?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a WordPress plugin that sends an ajax rest to GET some data from a REST endpoint:

```
register_rest_route('myplugin/v1/settings', [
    'methods' => \WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'getSettings',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
]);

function getSettings()
{
    $options = get_option('myplugin__options');
    if ($options == false) {
        return new \WP_Error(
            'rest_internal_server_error',
            'Unable to load settings',
            ['status' => 500]
        );
    }
    return $options;
}
```

The above code works fine but the issue is with response. When I check the response using Google's developer tools, I get this response:

```
<{
    "minify": true,
    "disableCommentsCookies": false,
    "disableEmojicons": false,
    "removeJQueryMigrate": false,
    "disableShortLinks": false,
    "disableQueryStrings": false,
    "moveScriptsToFooter": false,
    "deferScripts": false,
    "lazyLoadImages": false,
    "enableBrowserCache": false,
    "disableEmbed": false
}
```

Notice the "<" character. The data is saved to the database properly and there is no chevron character in it. Also, this issue only occurs when `minify` is set to true.

Does anyone of you guys came accross a similar situation? Thanks